# MSBuild does not create ClientBin folder?

Tags: silverlight, msbuild

I have a silverlight application. When i build the application using VS 2013, it creates ClientBin folder under web project and copies all XAP files into clientbin folder as expected.

However our build process use MSBuild to build all the applications. We have custom .proj file which has bunch of tasks to build the applications. When i execute .proj file using Msbuild command it doesn't not create ClientBin folder

Comment: Can you mention the exact command you run along with the parameters?

Comment: msbuild Main.proj /t:Clean;MyTarget1;MyTarget2;-p:Configuration=Release;DropLocation="C:\DropLocation";BuildNumber=999.99.1.1;VisualStudioVersion=12.0

Answer (score 1):

After checking around for problems similar to yours and looking at some of my silverlight projects I would suggest the following:

As you stated you are using a custom .proj file, you should check the custom .prog file and make sure this exists in a `<PropertyGroup/>`

```
<SilverlightApplicationList>{GUID}|..\Silverlight_Project_Folder\Silverlight_Project_Name.csproj|ClientBin|False</SilverlightApplicationList>
```

This value tells MSBuild to copy the XAP in the ClientBin directory.

Take note of the silverlight projects GUID. It can be obtained from the Silverlight app .csproj file:

```
<ProjectGuid>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</ProjectGuid>
```

There was also a mention of including the **CopySilverlightApplications;** task on the build server's *Microsoft.WebApplications.targets*

Hope this helps

References:

[New Silverlight app doesn't generate XAP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6981676/5233410)

[How to get the Silverlight XAP copied to the clientbin on build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207444/5233410)

[Silverlight xap file not being copied to ClientBin on Build Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981221/5233410)

[MSBuild SilverlightApplicationList](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0163a80b-e834-4f4e-a184-a86d045702c5/msbuild-silverlightapplicationlist)